# Triggering Local iOS Notifications on all Weekdays

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up local notifications that are triggered on all weekdays, ie: from Monday through Friday at 5pm, but NOT on weekends.
On Apple's Documentation, I found this way to trigger the notifications for all days:

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

dateComponents.hour = 17    // 17:00 hours

// Create the trigger as a repeating event.
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

But I'm unable to find out how to exclude specific days, ie: Saturday and Sunday, and set the time to 5pm. Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

first create a date object with

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600) // it may be any date whatever you want
```

To create the trigger from the date components:

```
let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
```

Now pass that date in UNCalendarNotificationTrigger with repeats true

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
```

Create a date with time :

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
let someDateTime = formatter.date(from: "2016/10/08 22:31") // put your date and time here
```

if Locale specific time :

```
 formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: How do I set the time to 5pm?

Comment: create a custom date with time of 5PM using DateComponents.

Comment: No, I was unable to do it